# How to pass a third param to EventHandler()

Tags: c#, onclick, controls, eventhandler

I wanted to generate a userControl from another, after preparing the userControl to receive Data, i am struggling with passing an int value to know which Card has been clicked to use it's data.

I know the code below is false i need a solution please help

```
 private BunifuThinButton2 generatetAributeStandBtn(int i)
    {
        BunifuThinButton2 button = new BunifuThinButton2();
        button.Name = "attributeBtn_" + i.ToString();
        button.Click += new EventHandler(this.button_Click);
        button.Size = new Size(114, 39);
        button.Location = new Point(30,150);


        return button;
    }


    private void button_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e, int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" Parents Name" +); 
        //actualModal = new confirmStandsModal();
        //this.Controls.Add(actualModal);
    }[Code Screen ][1]
```

Comment: @RajKamal No that doesnt work that way. You can only use this if you have control over the event invocation

Comment: Why can't you use the `Tag` property (which takes an object) to store this instead of trying to parse the `Name` property? It would definitely be better and less error prone than your current approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sender` parameter is the `Control` instance that has triggered the event, in your case the `BunifuThinButton2` instance. So you could either create a custom filed within that class (or derive a custom class first) or try to extract the ID from the `Name` property.

```
private void button_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var btn = sender as BunifuThinButton2;
    var id = int.Parse(btn.Name.Split(new [] {'_'})[1]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much! you've saved my Final test mark!